# materialization and performance for aggregation/concatenation of IEnumerable properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-sql

The question is at the end.

Here is the case

```
public class Head {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details {get; set;}
}

public class Detail {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Head Head {get; set;}
    public Int32 IType {get; set;}
    public String Code {get; set;}
}
```

My need is to fill a grid with at least two columns:

- Head.Id
- concatenation of Code value for said head and for a given Detail.Type value.

My first attempt was :

```
Int32 givenValue = 2;
var q = repo.Heads.
            Where(w.Expand()).
            Select(x => new {
                Id = x.IdFolder,
                Details = x.Details.Select(y => new { 
                    Id = y.Id,
                    IType = y.IType,
                    Code = y.Name
                })
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(taked).
            ToList().                            // One hit to the database
            Select(y => new {
                Id = y.Id,
                Codes2AsString = String.Join(
                    ",", 
                    y.Details.Where(z => z.IType == givenValue).Select(z => z.Code))
            }).
        ToList();
```

It works fine. (I know I should filter details on database side but I need the whole set for other concatenations.)

But: this code was 8 to 10 slower that is equivalent in Linq to SQL (I'm migrating an existing application) for 2850 heads. That is it takes 4 to 5 seconds to fill the grid, instead of nearly 0 second.

My second attempt was to aggregate/concatenate on database side, like in the old version of the application.

I create a view (with a tsql specificity)

```
create view as v_Head2Codes
select
    h.Id,         
    (
        select ',' + id.Code as [text()]
        from
            Details id
        Where  
            id.Header_Id == h.Id and id.IType = 2 
        order by id.Code
        For XML PATH ('')
    ) Codes
from
    Headers h
```

then I create a new class

```
public class VHead2Codes {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    public String Codes {get; set;}
}
```

I map this new class to the view and the modify my Head class

```
public class Head {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details {get; set;}

    public virtual VHead2Codes Codes2AsString {get; set;}
}
```

I set a One To One relation, and my query becomes

```
var q = repo.Heads.
            Where(w.Expand()).
            Select(x => new {
                Id = x.IdFolder,
                Codes2AsString = x.Codes2AsString.Codes
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(taked).
            ToList();                            // One hit to the database
```

Here I get the result and same performances as before.

My first guess is that the lost microprocessors cycles are used by the EF materialization process. **But it is probably wrong** (see second comment). Cycles are lost in the concatenation : loop over the heads and over the Details.

**My question is:** is there another way allowing to avoid the view by keeping the perfs ?

=====================================================================

======= on your request, the generated SQL ==========================

the linq query is:

```
Folders.Select(x => new {
    Id = x.IdFolder,
    Contribs = x.Contributors.Select(y => new {
        Name = y.Contributor.LastName
    })
})
```

the sql :

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[idDossier] AS [idDossier], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[ThirdParty_Id] AS [ThirdParty_Id], 
[Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[idDossier] AS [idDossier], 
    [Join1].[ThirdParty_Id] AS [ThirdParty_Id], 
    [Join1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join1].[ThirdParty_Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[tableD] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[ThirdParty_Id] AS [ThirdParty_Id], [Extent2].[TableD_Id] AS [TableD_Id], [Extent3].[LastName] AS [LastName]
        FROM  [dbo].[FolderContributions] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[v_ThirdParties] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[ThirdParty_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]) AND ([Extent2].[ThirdParty_Source] = [Extent3].[Source]) ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[idDossier] = [Join1].[TableD_Id]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[idDossier] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: Have you compared the generated queries (by L2S and EF)?

Comment: @Maarten honestly not, I just check that EF hits the db only once. But the L2S version uses an equivalent of the view, and the execution of the EF sql query in SSMS takes less than 0 seconds. I test by removing the concatenation (setting Codes2AsString to "") and the grid is filled much faster.

Comment: Are you sure that the Codes2AsString calculation does not issue subselects aka SELECT N+1?

Comment: @Firo: yes (that was my really first guess). I check this with LinqPad, only one hit to the database.

Comment: @tschmit007 one hit to db does not mean it works without subselects, and the subselects are not needed here, it should be a simple join.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy this query do not produce sql subselect. The linq subselect only allow to limit returned column.

Comment: can you post the sql generated plz?

Comment: @Firo generated sql posted

Answer (score 0):

You have overcomplicated the thing a little bit.
The following query should work, it would be a join in db, without subselects:

```
var givenValue = "t1";
var heads = new[] { // your repo.Heads query here: heads = repo.Heads.Where(w.Expand()).OrderBy(x => x.IdFolder).Take(taked);
    new {IdFolder = 1, Details = new[]{new {Code = "a", IType = "t1"}, new {Code = "b", IType = "t2"}}},
    new {IdFolder = 2, Details = new[]{new {Code = "c", IType = "t2"}, new {Code = "d", IType = "t1"}}},
};

// Db hit.
var q = heads; 
var details = q.SelectMany(
    h=>h.Details
        .Where(d=>d.IType == givenValue)
        .Select(d=>new{HeadId = h.IdFolder, d.Code})).ToList();

// O(N) in-memory.
var grid = details
    .ToLookup(d=>d.HeadId)
    .Select(g=>new{HeadId = g.Key, Codes = string.Join(",",g.Select(i=>i.Code))})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: the query do not produce sql subselect. The linq subselect only allow to limit returned column.